# Interrupt CompletableFuture with default value

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

Suppose I have 3 services.
First I call `serviceA`, it returns a `CompletableFuture`.
After that with the result I call `serviceB` and `serviceC` paralelly (`thenCompose()`).
After I have all result I would like to combine all 3 results and return it to some caller.
In the caller I would like to wait overall X millseconds to the whole process so that:

- If I interrupt the process while `serviceA` call is in progress: throw some exception (so it is mandatory)
- If I interrupt the process while `serviceB` and `serviceC` calls are in progress: return some default value (they are optional).
  This is the reason I try to use the `getNow(fallback)` method of the `CompletableFuture`

Please check below my code snippets, if I use long delays in `serviceB` and `serviceC` calls, I always ends up with a `TimeoutException`.
How can I do this?

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> getFuture() {
    CompletableFuture<A> resultA = serviceA.call();
    CompletableFuture<B> resultB = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<C> resultC = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceC.call(a));
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(resultB, resultC)
            .thenApply(ignoredVoid -> combine(
                    resultA.join(),
                    resultB.getNow(fallbackB),
                    resultC.getNow(fallbackC));
}

public Result extractFuture(CompletableFuture<Result> future) {
    Result result;
    try {
        result = future.get(timeOut, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        ...
    } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException ex) {
        // I always ends up here...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future returned by `.allOf(resultB, resultC)` is only completed when both, `resultB` and `resultC` are completed, therefore, the dependent function `ignoredVoid -> combine(resultA.join(), resultB.getNow(fallbackB), resultC.getNow(fallbackC)` will only get evaluated if `resultB` and `resultC` are completed and providing a fallback has no effect at all.

It is generally impossible to react on a `get()` call within these function. Which should be obvious considering that there can be an arbitrary number of `get()` calls on the future at different times with different timeouts, but the function passed to `thenApply` is only evaluated once.

The only way to handle a consumer specified timeout within `getFuture()` is to change it to return a function which receives the timeout:

```
interface FutureFunc<R> {
    R get(long time, TimeUnit u) throws ExecutionException;
}
public FutureFunc<Result> getFuture() {
    CompletableFuture<A> resultA = serviceA.call();
    CompletableFuture<B> resultB = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<C> resultC = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceC.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<Result> optimistic = CompletableFuture.allOf(resultB, resultC)
        .thenApply(ignoredVoid -> combine(resultA.join(), resultB.join(), resultC.join()));
    return (t,u) -> {
        try {
            return optimistic.get(t, u);
        } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException ex) {
            return combine(resultA.join(), resultB.getNow(fallbackB),
                                           resultC.getNow(fallbackC));
        }
    };
}

public Result extractFuture(FutureFunc<Result> future) {
    Result result;
    try {
        result = future.get(timeOut, MILLISECONDS);
    } catch (ExecutionException ex) {
        ...
    }
    return result;
}
```

Now, different calls with different timeouts can be made, with possibly different outcome as long as B or C have not completed yet. Not that there is some ambiguity regarding the `combine` method which may also take some time.

You could change the function to a

```
return (t,u) -> {
    try {
        if(resultB.isDone() && resultC.isDone()) return optimistic.get();
        return optimistic.get(t, u);
    } catch (InterruptedException | TimeoutException ex) {
        return combine(resultA.join(), resultB.getNow(fallbackB),
                                       resultC.getNow(fallbackC));
    }
};
```

to wait for the completion of a possibly already running `combine`. In either case, there is no guaranty that the result is delivered within the specified time, as even if the fallback values for B and C are used, there will be an execution of `combine` that may take an arbitrary amount of time.

If you want cancellation like behavior, i.e. that all result queries return the same result, even if it has been calculated using the fallback values due to the first query, you can use instead

```
public FutureFunc<Result> getFuture() {
    CompletableFuture<A> resultA = serviceA.call();
    CompletableFuture<B> resultB = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<C> resultC = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceC.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<Void> bAndC = CompletableFuture.allOf(resultB, resultC);
    CompletableFuture<Result> result = bAndC
        .thenApply(ignoredVoid -> combine(resultA.join(), resultB.join(),
                                                          resultC.join()));
    return (t,u) -> {
        try {
            bAndC.get(t, u);
        } catch (InterruptedException|TimeoutException ex) {
            resultB.complete(fallbackB);
            resultC.complete(fallbackC);
        }
        try {
            return result.get();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            throw new ExecutionException(ex);
        }
    };
}
```

With this, all queries on a single `FutureFunc` will consistently return the same result, even if it is based on fallback values due to the first timeout. This variant also consistently excludes the execution of `combine` from the timeout.

Of course, if different timeouts are not intended at all, you could refactor `getFuture()` to get the desired timeout in advance, e.g. as parameter. That would simplify the implementation significantly and it could return a future again:

```
public CompletableFuture<Result> getFuture(long timeOut, TimeUnit u) {
    CompletableFuture<A> resultA = serviceA.call();
    CompletableFuture<B> resultB = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceB.call(a));
    CompletableFuture<C> resultC = resultA.thenCompose(a -> serviceC.call(a));
    ScheduledExecutorService e = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    e.schedule(() -> resultB.complete(fallbackB), timeOut, u);
    e.schedule(() -> resultC.complete(fallbackC), timeOut, u);
    CompletableFuture<Void> bAndC = CompletableFuture.allOf(resultB, resultC);
    bAndC.thenRun(e::shutdown);
    return bAndC.thenApply(ignoredVoid ->
                           combine(resultA.join(), resultB.join(), resultC.join()));
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. It works like a charm, thanks for the detailed answer!